# Exclude files except the minified version in NuSpec file

Tags: nuget-package, nuspec

I have a NuSpec file to create a NuGet package. I have some .js files that are minified and I don't want the original .js files in the NuGet package.

I have tried to use `!` to not exclude minified files.

```xml
<files>
    <file src="v1\**" target="v1" exclude="!v1\**\*.min.js;v1\**\*.js" />
</files>
```

This only doesn't work, it will delete the `.js` and `.min.js` files.

What kind of syntax can I use to achieve this?

Comment: is there also an `include="**\*min.js"` ? some msbuild props have this.

Comment: @sommmen Unfortunately include is not an accepted property :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found any solution to do this as I had imagined. It seems to me that it is simply not possible. There is also no mention of doing something similar in the [nuspec documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec).

My solution finally was to split the files rows like this.

```xml
<files>
    <!--Move all minified js files-->
    <file src="v1\js\js1\*.min.js" target="v1\js\js1\" />
    <file src="v1\js\js2\*.min.js" target="v1\js\js2\" />

    <!--The rest of the files that are not js and exclude all source js files-->
    <file src="v1\js\**" target="v1\js\" exclude="v1\js\**\*.js" />
</files>
```

I had to be more specific than I wanted to be because `target` doesn't allow the use of `*`.